# Why it doesnt put it into the mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay i have another problem now. This should put the serial into the mysql database but instead it only puts in the first letter of the serial. how to make it write the whole string?

```
    $str = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
    {
        if($letter_OR_number = rand(0,1))
        { // true: alphabet chosen
            $str[] = chr(rand(65, 90));
        }
        else
        { // false: number chosen
            $str[] = rand(0,9);
        }
        if($i % 4 == 3)
        {
            ($i < 19)? $str[] = '-': $str[] = ' ';
        }
    }
        $Query = "INSERT INTO `Donates` (`serial`, `Coins`) VALUES ('%s', '500')";
        mysql_query(vsprintf($Query, $str),$link) or die(mysql_error());
    foreach($str as $val){
        echo $val;
    }


    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you [read the manual for `mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) recently? Why persist with deprecated functions?

Comment: adding error reporting, in this case `mysql_error()` is always an easy step for debugging - `mysql_query(vsprintf($Query, $Data),$Verbinding) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Okay thanks Sean that helped alot. But it says no database select when i clearly select a database in there dont i?

Comment: Do you check the return code of `mysql_select_db`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: Because the access was denied.

Comment: Okay i got it working but now it puts every character in a new row. How to get it all in one row

Comment: If you do `echo "<pre>".print_r($TestData,1)."</pre>";` right after `foreach($str as $val){...}`, but before `foreach($TestData as $Data){..` you will see that `$TestData` is an array of single chars, not your 24 char value - `1Q99-QR11-67GJ-328O-R3S5`

Comment: How can i pack them together and put them in a single row?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what your code actually is intended to do,

```
if($letter_OR_number = rand(0,1))
```

should be

```
if($letter_OR_number == rand(0,1))
```

In

```
$TestData[] = array($val);
```

you create an array of arrays, thus

```
$TestData[] = $val;
```

might be what you wanted ...

Comment: I got the debug on because of sean now.. It says it has no database selected when it clearly has?

Comment: Make sure the database name is spelled correctly, depending on your installation it might be case sensitive. Check if your database user has the necessary privileges?

Comment: Okay i got it working but now it puts every character in a new row. How to get it all in one row

Answer (score 0):

Why create 2 arrays, when in the end you just want a string. Try something like this -

```
$str = ''; // create a string, not an array
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
{
    if($letter_OR_number = rand(0,1))
    { // true: alphabet chosen
        $str .= chr(rand(65, 90));
    }
    else
    { // false: number chosen
        $str .= rand(0,9);
    }
    if($i % 4 == 3)
    {
        ($i < 19)? $str .= '-': $str .= ' ';
    }
}

$Query = "INSERT INTO `Donates` SET `serial` = '%s', `Coins` = '500'";
mysql_query(vsprintf($Query, $str),$Verbinding);
```

**edit**
if you still want to use `$str[]` then you need to implode before.

```
$str = ''; 
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) { 
    if($letter_OR_number = rand(0,1)) { // true: alphabet chosen 
        $str[] = chr(rand(65, 90)); } 
    else { // false: number chosen 
        $str[] = rand(0,9); } 
    if($i % 4 == 3) { 
        ($i < 19)? $str[] = '-': $str[] = ' '; } 
} 
foreach($str as $val){ 
      echo $val; } 

$str = implode("",$str); // Implode to make your array a string    

$Query = "INSERT INTO Donates (serial, Coins) VALUES ('%s', '500')";
mysql_query(vsprintf($Query, $str),$link) or die(mysql_error()); mysql_close($link); ?>
```

Comment: See my edit. If you still use `$str[]` then you need to implode the array before inserting `$str = implode("",$str);`

Comment: Or you can change all your `$str[] =` to `$str .=` to keep it a string, like in my first example

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is create 20-character unique identifier for your coins, by creating a mixture of letters and numbers in groups of four.

PHP and MySQL both provide a function which will generate a random string albeit with slight differences. Such a string is usually called a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) (universally unique identifier).  This is actually a standard since such a thing is a requirement in many systems.

The PHP function [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) will generate a random string of either 13 or 23 characters; based on the timestamp.  Here is a sample run:

```
print uniqid();  # 151cfeeba8b833
print uniqid('', true); # 51cfeeba8b83f6.48956452
```

Now, this doesn't give the number in the format you are looking for. However, there is a [comment on the manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#94959) which provides a handy function:

```
function v4() {
    return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',

      // 32 bits for "time_low"
      mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

      // 16 bits for "time_mid"
      mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

      // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
      // four most significant bits holds version number 4
      mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,

      // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
      // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
      // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
      mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,

      // 48 bits for "node"
      mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
    );
}
```

This is called v4 because it is the "version 4" of the UUID specs.  Here is a sample string from that function `edd08995-9d48-4e04-8e42-5270377c331f`.

MySQL has a built-in [uuid function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) that does the exact same thing:

```
mysql> SELECT UUID();
        -> '6ccd780c-baba-1026-9564-0040f4311e29'
```

You can use this to simplify your code, and then all you have is:

```
<?php

  $q = "INSERT INTO `Donates` (`serial`, `Coins`) VALUES (UUID(), '500')";
  mysql_query($q, $link) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

You should use the `mysqli_*` functions, as the older mysql functions will be removed from PHP. See [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) in the manual for a discussion on which API to use.

Here is your example with `mysqli`:

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Error: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $q = "INSERT INTO `Donates` (`serial`, `Coins`) VALUES (UUID(), '500')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($q);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Error: ".$mysqli->error;
    }
?>
```